# Storing objects in ArrayList instead of Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I currently have a program that stores objects in an array that I need to store in an `ArrayList` instead.

This is how the objects were originally stored.

```
private String phrase = "Once upon a time";
private Letter[] letter_array = new Letter[16];

for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
  letter_array[i] = new Letter(phrase.charAt(i));
  }
```

So now, I'm trying to use something like this instead.

```
private String phrase = "Once upon a time";
ArrayList<Letter> aToZ = new ArrayList<Letter>();

for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
  Letter x = new Letter.charAt(i);
  aToZ.add(x);
  }
```

Some of the code has been omitted, but these are the pertinent parts.

This doesn't work and I've tried variations, but I just really don't know how to do this.

Comment: What your **Letter** class does?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you have any stacktrace or output in your console log? It's difficult to help you if we don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
Letter x = new Letter.charAt(i);
```

you need

```
Letter x = new Letter(phrase.charAt(i));
```

in your 2nd code snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
Letter x = new Letter(phrase.charAt(i));
```

You almost had it! You need to include the "phrase." before charAt, but everything else seems to be correct.

Try to think of the object > string > charAt sequence carefully when you reread your code. Ask yourself when you read over your code: "what is it exactly about the object that I want to reference/change?"